# Does warden's mark lower enemies attack rolls?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark, warden

As far as I know a warden marks his/her enemies in order to exploit Warden's Fury and Warden's Grasp immediate at-wills. But in Primal Power, page 95, Daily Evocations lvl 5,
Lifebind Attack states:

**Effect:** While the target is marked by you, its penalty to
attack rolls for the marked condition is -5 instead of -2.

Is there something I'm missing? Where is it stated that warden's mark acts the same as fighter's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Marked** is a condition in 4e. It can be applied by most Defender classes, and is how they're able to "defend". The definition for the Marked condition includes the following:

> The creature takes a -2 penalty to attack rolls for any attack that
>   doesn’t include the marking creature as a target.
>   (Player's Handbook, p. 277)

This means that the Warden's mark is the same as the Fighter's because they are both marks. The Warden's class feature does not mimic the Fighter's class feature; instead both class features make use of the same non-class-specific "mark" mechanic (even Rogues can pick up powers which let them use marks).